# How to change footer in WordPress if there is < 5 posts?

Tags: wordpress, nav

Okay, so I made a Wordpress theme, and everything works perfectly, except the fact that:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pagination">                
   <li id="left">
          <?php posts_nav_link('','<span class="previous">&rarr;</span>','<span class="next">&larr;</span>'); ?>
       </li>
</div><!-- end .pagination -->
 </div><!-- end .wrapper -->
```

shows up when there are less than 5 posts.  For example, If I go to a category that has 6 posts, and click on the bottom navigation to go see the last post from that category—since I only allow 5 posts per page—the nav works perfectly!  BUT..if there is a category that only has 2 posts, and I allow 5, the styling for that nav still shows up.  **Is there an if/else statement that allows me to say, "if page displays < 5 posts, show this footer (without the posts_nav_link included) ?"**

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just do an if on the count of your post variable....I dunno what it is though so I've just included it as $postvariable....its likely something else though.  I don't use wordpress so I don't know what it is....but it will be something along these lines......

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pagination">
    <?if(count($yourpostvariable)>=5){?>    
   <li id="left">
          <?php posts_nav_link('','<span class="previous">&rarr;</span>','<span class="next">&larr;</span>'); ?>
       </li>
      <?};?>
</div><!-- end .pagination -->
 </div><!-- end .wrapper -->
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work correctly, but it makes sense.  I don't know what  $yourpostvariable is suppost to be.

Comment: Like I said....$yourpostvariable is just what I put in there, cuz I don't know the variable to your posts.  Never used wordpress. You need to find the variable of the posts on your page somewhere....know what I mean?